# Почему старое ПО использует только ядро

Tags: многопоточность, ос

Есть всякое старое ПО времен, когда многоядерные процессоры не были распространены.

Так вот, оно как правило загружает только 1 ядро, хотя, по идее, там должны были использоваться потоки.

Разве не ОС контролирует распределение потоков по ядрам?

Например, какой-нибудь там старый STALKER есть только 1 ядро.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На системе с одним процессорным ядром не имело большого смысла делать несколько потоков, занимающихся вычислениями. Наоборот, это могло привести к некоторому замедлению из-за обеспечения синхронизации.

Потоки делались для обеспечения задач ввода-вывода и  других, где могло требоваться ожидание, нарушающее взаимодействие с пользователем.

Пример:
Основной поток - отвечает за user interface
Вторичные потоки - работа с базой данных, работа с сетью
Расчёты - если они долгие, то могли быть вынесены в отдельный поток. Но обычно в один.

Answer (score 1):

Да, ОС заведует распределением потоков по ядрам. Но создаёт потоки, распределяет логику программы на независимые части и обеспечивает их синхронизацию только разработчик. Как ОС поймёт, какую часть из тысяч последовательных команд нужно выделять в отдельные потоки? Сколько их создавать? Когда нужно их синхронизировать?

Однако существуют алгоритмы, которые способны автоматически разделять программы на независимые потоки, но оно довольно громоздкие, не делают этого во время исполнения / на лету и не встроены в ОС. В интернете полно научных статей на эту тему: [algorithm for automatic detection of program parallelism](https://google.gik-team.com/?q=algorithm+for+automatic+detection+of+program+parallelism).